# Record clustering based on Place and Time in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I would like to know if any of you guys have written a query for record clustering based on overlapping time intervals AND locations.
Data in my application is represented as individual events of a person being at any given location from start time to end time. Location is defined as latitude and longitude. During a day one person will have multiple different locations and start and end times. I need to get groups of persons who were at the same location and at the same time. One person will most likely be in several groups during a day.

```
Example:
Person A can be with Person B at the office from 10 AM to 11 AM.
Then Person A leaves the office for gym.
There he is with Person C from 12 noon to 1PM.
At 12:30 Person C leaves gym for the office.
At 1:30PM I have Person B and C at the office.
Persons B and C leave the office at 5PM.
```

In this example I have

- Cluster 1 (Person A and B at the office) from 10AM to 11AM,
- Cluster 2 (Person A and C at the gym) from 12 noon to 1PM, and
- Cluster 3 (Person B and C at the office) from 1:30PM to 5PM.

The Location of each individual person will not match exactly to another person's location. I'm using SQL geography point type with the STBuffer of proximity threshold and check for STIntersects. I'm also joining the table on itself to check time overlaps. But i'm experiencing some weird behaviors when Person A gets clustered on itself without other person ever joining him.

I'm wondering if there's a design pattern for handling situations like this. Ideally i would have the recordset grouped on "Overlapping Time Period" and "Centroid of an arbitrary geometry" but can't figure out how to get the overlapping time period and the arbitrary geometry.

Any ideas are welcome and highly appreciated.

P.S. writing a windows application is not an option unless it's the only way.

EDIT: Failed to mention that locations of clustering is never known in advance. There can be indefinite number of locations where two or more of my customers may cluster. I don't know if clustering will happen in the office, gym, some park or at a bus station. Clustering location (i think ) will be the Centroid of a polygon represented by all congregated people's Latitudes and Longitudes.

Comment: The point is that because you have no idea where the clustering will occur, you need to set up a fairly blocky buffer, say the size of a park to catch two people "clustering" for a morning run. This size however becomes too large, because entire adjacent office blocks are now also considered as "clustered"

Comment: For simplicity let's say that i want to know each time two or more persons are standing within 100 feet of each other at the same time. I'd like to know the location of the occurrence and the overlapping time period of those two being near each other.

Comment: You need a time buffer as well, unless your recording clocks are in sync down to the milliseconds. How many (milli)seconds would you say constitutes "at the same time"?

Comment: Well, i don't really see why i would need a time buffer if i have ArrivedAt and DepartedAt datetimes for each event. I just check for overlaps.

Comment: You might need that in cases like when certain two periods do not overlap just because the arrive time of one is a couple of seconds later than the leave time of the other, but in fact the sources that recorded the timestamps are a couple of minutes out of sync with each other, and if it were not for that fact, the two periods would have overlapped.

Comment: No, the time is recorded on SQL Server side. Whenever event is raised SQL Stamps the time, so the events are all synced up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the puzzle by first getting the entire dataset for the given time period. Looping through the recordset and generating STUnion shapes for all overlapping locations. Then joining the generated temporary table on the initial datased and getting only the records that intersected with STUnion shapes AND with each other in time.
Used three temp tables but hey, who cares if it does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

Would the code be something like

```
select a.person,a.eventtime,a.eventplace,
b.person,b.eventtime,b.eventplace
from people a
join people b on a.eventtime between dateadd(hh,-2,b.eventime) and dateadd(hh,2,b.eventime)
and yourdistancefunction(a.eventplace ,b.eventplace) < 5 -- don't know what you are measuring
and a.person<>b.person
```